# AngularJS scope variable not being set within promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cartodb

I have this code that I'm using with CartoDB. It's suppose to run a query using their JS library and then return some data. I'm adding up some results *and it works inside the done() function*. Though the second I try use/set the result as a scope variable in AngularJS, I lose it. Here's some example code.
**EDIT:** My Apologies, "doesnt work" means that i always get the default value of mvcTotal = 0, isntead of what is computed inside the JS.

```
angular.module('angMvcApp')
  .controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var borough = $routeParams.borough;

    var sql = new cartodb.SQL({user: 'wkaravites'});
    var table = 'qiz3_axqb';
    var mvcTotal = 0;

    if (borough != null) {
      $scope.borough = borough;
    } else {
      $scope.borough = "Data Overview";

      sql.execute("select borough, count(*) from qiz3_axqb group by borough")
        .done(function (data) {
          $.each(data.rows, function (index, value) {
            console.log("pizza: " +value['count']);
            mvcTotal += value['count'];
            //$('#' + value['borough'] + '').text(value['count']);
            //$('#boroughList').append('<h2>' + value['borough'] + '</h2>');

          });
          //I see this correct
          console.log(mvcTotal +" totals");

          //This doesn't work
          $scope.mvcTotal = mvcTotal;

        })
        .error(function (errors) {
          // errors contains a list of errors
          console.log("errors:" + errors);
        });
      console.log(mvcTotal+" test test");

      //This doesn't work
      $scope.mvcTotal = mvcTotal;

      //This works
      #scope.mvcTotal = 57;

    }


  }]);
```

Am I messing something up with how I'm translating a regular variable to an Angular scope variable? When I check the JS console, I see the log with pizza in it AND the correct number with "totals" appended to the end.

Here is the HTML view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>{{borough}}</h1>
      <p>{{mvcTotal}} motor vehicle collisions</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying defining $scope.mvcTotal at the top before you run the query. e.g. $scope.mvcTotal;  var       sql = new cartodb.SQL({user: 'wkaravites'});
    var table = 'qiz3_axqb';
    var mvcTotal = 0;

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague. We don't know what the expected behavior of your program is. Do you mean it does not appear in the html view? You should include the html view. Is it just that the console.log message is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to do with the data returned from your DB call must be done INSIDE the done function. I think you understand that, but what you are missing is the order of operations. Use a debugger to see the actual order in which the code is executed:

```
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({user: 'wkaravites'});

//step #1
var mvcTotal = 0;

  //step #2
  sql.execute("select borough, count(*) from qiz3_axqb group by borough")
    .done(function (data) {
      //step #6 finally after DB responds this is called. mvcTotal is still 0
      //$scope.mvcTotal is 57
      $.each(data.rows, function (index, value) {
        console.log("pizza: " +value['count']);
        mvcTotal += value['count'];


      });
      //step #7 now you get the correct total
      console.log(mvcTotal +" totals");

      //step #8 this is correct. you can display this value in your html view as {{mvcTotal}}
      $scope.mvcTotal = mvcTotal;

    })


  //step #3 mvcTotal is still 0
  console.log(mvcTotal+" test test");


  //step #4 mvcTotal is still 0 since DB call has not finished
  $scope.mvcTotal = mvcTotal;

  //step #5 previous value was 0, now it's 57
  $scope.mvcTotal = 57;
```

Comment: I tried that, just putting it inside the DONE function and I still get 0 as the value in HTML for mvcTotal. Also, put a better explanation in.

Comment: Weird, it randomly works and then sometimes randomly doesn't.

Comment: I would completely remove the code below the `sql.execute` statement (steps 3-5). That is just going to confuse things.